# Funcion flecha de js

Tags: javascript

Usando este código en el navegador:

```
const ArrowFun=(num1,num2)=>{num1+num2};
let result=ArrowFun(2,3);
console.log(result);
```

Al ejecutarlo me aparece `undefined` . Entiendo que el `return` está implícito en la función flecha, entonces **¿por qué no genera el valor 5?**

Comment: está implícito cuando no está entre llaves, para que no pongas el `return` debes de quitarle esas llaves, `const ArrowFun=(num1,num2)=>num1+num2;`

Comment: Claro sacando los paréntesis funciona correctamente. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

De la forma en la que lo tienes actualmente:

```
const ArrowFun=(num1,num2)=>{num1+num2};
let result=ArrowFun(2,3);
console.log(result);
```

No estas haciendo un `return`, sino que estas calculando `num1+num2` simplemente, sin devolverlo y sin hacer nada mas. Y eso es por que esta entre los corchetes, para solucionarlo como bien menciono Oscar GG en su comentario, debes de eliminarlos y la función te devolverá el resultado esperado.

```
const ArrowFun=(num1,num2)=> num1+num2;
let result=ArrowFun(2,3);
console.log(result);
```